# Running rsync shell command in php

Tags: php, rsync

I am trying to do a `rsync` from `amazon cloud` to my local machine by using php.

I have

```
$copy = 'rsync -acz ubuntu@ec3-51-123-131-111.compute-1.amazonaws.com:/project/file.txt .'

shell_exec ($copy)
```

However, the file is not copied and there is no error message as well. Can anyone give me a hint about it? Thanks so much!

Comment: Have you tried running it from the shell command line?  What was the result?

Comment: I believe there may be an error message on STDERR, this would possibly end up in your web servers' error log, and not in the page output as STDOUT might.

Comment: what ssh key are you using? Is it asking for a password or have you set it up with a keychain / passwordless login? Remember I had a similar issue a while ago that was solved with using keychain.

Comment: is rsync in th path? `which rsync` may be /bin/rsync should work better in script?

Answer (score 1):

There are a few things that could be going wrong here. First of all, you are missing a semi colon at the end of the `$copy` variable declaration. Your script should be

```
$copy = 'rsync -acz user@server:/home/user/foo.txt .';
shell_exec ($copy);
```

If that is just a typo in your post and not the way the real script is, make sure you can run the command correctly from a terminal, without needing to enter a password. If you can, launch your php script again but monitor your error logs. Assuming you are running this script through a an apache webserver, that would be

```
tail -f /var/log/apache2/error.log
```